# how to deselect all the items on desktop in win xp sp3?

Tags: windows-xp

when I use win D to go to desktop,the focus is always on the latest used item icon on desktop, somehow i need to create new files on desktop, and that requires the effect of 'right click on the desktop' , how to deselect all the items on desktop in win xp sp3, so that i can use mouseless shortcut to create new folder or new word doc?

Comment: You know that your keyboard has a left mouse click key, right? Wouldn't that work?

Comment: Keyboards have right-click button, not left click.

Answer (score 1):

F5 (refresh) will do it.  Or ALT+V, then R (also refresh).

Or ALT+E, then I (invert selection), followed by CTRL+SPACE (to deselect the one icon left).

Comment: START+START also works. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard No it doesn't. All the items will still be selected after pressing START+START. Its just the desktop no longer has focus. As soon as focus is returned, they're still selected.